# Function, array and dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have done this so far, i donot know where my mistake is or where i m going wrong, I have come up with this program 1st time. We have to ask from the user amount of elements in an array which i have done using dynamic array. Then we have to pass 2 arguments one is the size of an array and the other is array(float type).

The function should replace the contents of each cell with the sum of the contents of all the cells in the original array from the left end to the cell in question. for example if i have array {1,2,3,4,5}  function should return {1,3,6,10,15}. This is my program below please tell me what changes I have to make in my existing code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float compute(int x, float arr[]){
    float sum=0;

    for(int i=0; i<x;i++){
        sum+=arr[i];
        arr[i]=sum;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(){
    int x;
    cout<<"How many elements you want"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    float *p=new float[x];

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        cin>>p[i];
    }
    cout<<compute(x,p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any idea what `float compute(int x, float arr[])` returns ?

Comment: This code is leaky, you're never deallocating the dynamically allocated array, it would be a lot safer if you just used `std::vector<float>` instad.

Comment: It should return another array for example the input I have taken from the user is  {1,2,3,4,5}, function should return {1,3,6,10,15}.it is simply adding the previous one.

Comment: FYI, there is a standard library algorithm for this called [`std::partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum)

Comment: want to do this without library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void compute(int x, float arr[]){
    float sum=0;

    for(int i=0; i<x;i++){
        sum+=arr[i];
        arr[i]=sum;
    }
}

int main(){

    int x;
    cout<<"How many elements you want"<<endl;
    cin>>x;

    float *p=new float[x];

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        cin>>p[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        cout << p[i] << endl;
    }

    compute(x,p);
    cout << "----"<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        cout << p[i] << endl;
    }
    delete[] p;
    return 0;
}
```

### Notes

```
float compute(int x, float arr[])
{
...
return arr;
}
```

You declare the return type of compute as a `float` and then return arr which has the type of `float[]`. These types are not compatible.

---

You cannot expect `cout` to print an array.

```
 cout<<compute(x,p);
```

In C and C++ an array is actually passed by the memory address of its first element. There is no way for cout to know how to print an array.

---

When you create an array using `new`, you will always have to use the `delete[]` operator to free the memory you previously allocated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have clearly understood, Thanks very much................... . Tell me one thing just if we use delete operator, can we again fill the array and do whatever we want??

Comment: No, after the delete, you should not touch the memory referenced by the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fixes, if you can modify original array

```
void compute(int x, float arr[]) 
{ 
    float sum=0;

    for(int i=1; i<x ;i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1];

    // return arr; // Not required
}
```

And then, you can do following

```
compute(x,p);
for(int i= 0 ; i< x; ++i)
   std::cout<< p[i] << std::endl;
```

Also, make sure to release the allocated memory, after processing

`delete [] p;`

Comment: What about the safer `std::vector<float>` based version? Say one that doesn't mutate function arguments...

Comment: Please answer my this question.... Are arrays always passed by reference when using function???

Comment: @user3100177 Here the array is decaying to pointer while passing it as argument, and the function modifies it, you should learn to use `std::vector` and `std::partial_sum` as others suggested, this answer is more or less C style approach